# component Re-rendering not working synchronously

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

in my react app,
 i want to change the data as deleted for particular value of data using a delete button(that onclick done axios delete to API). the delete option works properly. but on re-rendering the data on table, table value shows the previous data(not showing the data as DELETED)even though i called the API after delete function.But after refreshing the page, i called the API,fetched, table shows the correct value as "DELETED". Why this happen and how to fix it? please help me to fix it..

Comment: Please provide your code, I think you have to update the state value after you get success response in the delete API call to the server.

Comment: It is successfully being updated when you reload the page.